# GPG "No valid OpenPGP data found"

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have a number of files I previously encrypted with a symmetric key using GnuPG 2.2.4, on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Although I have successfully decrypted them in the past, for some unknown reason, I get an error now.

I recently tested my key and basic commands with a test file (test.ods) and that seems to work. To compare the test file and my files, I tried gpg --verify file.

Output of gpg --verify test.ods.gpg

- gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error (perhaps not an issue
  for what I want to do...)

Output of gpg --verify myfile.gpg

- **gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found**
- gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error

Output of gpg -d myfile.gpg > myfile.gpg

Error "Bad session key"

Does the no data found error mean that the data is corrupted/lost? Are there other ways to check the contents of the encrypted file for integrity?

#

Update: I luckily had some backup files containing most of the contents. These were also encrypted with the same key. However, unlike the file above, I was able to decrypt it.

I think the root cause is related to making corrupt .zip file prior encryption (myfile.zip). Then for some reason gpg is able to encrypt, gpg -c myfile.zip > myfile.gpg, but not decrypt it, gpg -d myfile.gpg > myfile.zip
Does this seem plausable?

Comment: Getting exactly this issue. Advice or updates appreciated.